# How can I give the option select year in core Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to generate option select (say 2013 - 2015) in [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Here is my HTML code

```
<select name="year">
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

How can I convert this to core Laravel?

**Update :**

How can I do this for 1990 - 2000 for more years?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Have you checked out [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) ?

Comment: actually i am beginner so i don't have any idea pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
{{ Form::selectYear('year', 2013, 2015) }}
```

to generate 1990 to 2000

You should use

```
{{ Form::selectYear('year', 1990, 2000) }}
```

Read more about HTML and Forms from Laravel's [Official Website](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html)

Comment: Worth noting that the HTML generation package for Laravel (this includes forms) is no longer installed by default in Laravel 5. It needs to be loaded in your composer file in versions of Laravel after 4.2.